# IE7/8 ignoring file download request in popup

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer

I'm using Silverlight and I need to allow the user to save some dynamically genereated files.

For PDF files I created an http handler and it works just fine when I open it in a popup window.

For Excel files I tried every combination of `Content-type` and `Content-disposition` but IE8 refuses to open the file. With Fiddler I can see the get and there's a very short display of an IE window but it closes straight away.

I can't see any error message anywhere and I can't find any other description of the issue. IE7 exhibits the same behaviour.

I tried `Content-type` = application/vnd.ms-excel, application/unknown, application/octet-stream
and for for `Content-disposition` I tried inline and attachment.

PS: I can't use the SL built-in save dialog because it requires the context to be within a user action and I generate the file asychronously on the server.

Comment: Excel 2003. But IE should get me at least an open/save dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like automatic prompting for downloads is disabled. See [this](http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/06/Disappearing-IE-Popup-Window-During-SaveOpen-Dialog.cfm) description on how to enable automatic prompting. Enabling automatic prompting worked for me (situation: silverlight app uses Window.Navigate to open a popup to a generic handler that generates an excel file, with content-disposition: attachment, which worked fine in FF, but not in IE8).
As this post is already pretty old, I'm curious if you found a better way to solve this!

Comment: I can't remember the magic incantation that fixed it. I had a look at the code and I can see that I trigger the popup using HtmlPage.PopupWindow(<full path.xls>, "_blank", null); and then create the file with the "Cache-Control: private", "Content-Length: <the length>", "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel", "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.xls>". I can see that I had to comment out the "context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();" line so I think that was causing the issue (or so the comment says). Hope you can fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Content-Disposition: attachment

Have you tried on another client?  My guess is maybe that Office is trying to get kicked off and is failing.

Alternatively, it's possibly related to http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/Internet-Explorer-cannot-download-over-HTTPS-when-no-cache.aspx

Comment: FF works perfectly fine. And as i said I did use `Content-Disposition: attachment` (and I tried `inline` as well for good measure). I noticed the `No-Cache` because when I set it PDF wouldn't work neither.
I think my option's going to be to use a hidden `iframe`. Looks like that's how other professional sites trigger downloads.